# LaTeX: Multiple authors stays on same line

Tags: line-breaking, author

I have 5 authors for a paper currently added like so:

```
\author{First Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\\And
  Second Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\\And
  Third Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\\And
  Fourth Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\\And
  Fifth Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\
}
```

Currently they are displayed on the same line and overlapping like so:
[image]

I thought that LaTeX would automatically break this line, but apparently not. I would prefer to have 3 on the top row and then 2 beneath, but I haven't found how to do this properly. Found some hacks, but then I lose styling on the lower row.

**Edit:** After some investigating it seems to be the style package used that cases the issue. We have to use this style package since this is an assignment. Here is the style code regarding the different `\and` tags.

```
{\def\and{\unskip\enspace{\rm and}\enspace}%
 \def\And{\end{tabular}\hss \egroup \hskip 1in plus 2fil 
       \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf}%
 \def\AND{\end{tabular}\hss\egroup \hfil\hfil\egroup
      \vskip 0.25in plus 1fil minus 0.125in
       \hbox to \linewidth\bgroup\large \hfil\hfil
         \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf}
 \hbox to \linewidth\bgroup\large \hfil\hfil
 \hbox to 0pt\bgroup\hss \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\bf\@author 
                        \end{tabular}\hss\egroup
 \hfil\hfil\egroup
}
```

What would be the best way to work around this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What document class are you using?

Comment: \author is defined by the document class, but normally authors are separated by `\and` or by using multiple `\author` commands, depending on what the class defines.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle @egreg We are using the article document class and only the last `\author` is shown if we have multiple of them. Right now we use `\and` to join them in one `\author` expression.

Comment: with `article` class one `\author` command and using `\and` is the right thing, but your fragment uses some undefined command `\And` please post a complete small document that shows the problem it is impossible to test anything with the question as it is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle We have a style package we must use since this is an assignment, and that seems to be the cause of the weird behavior. Check out the edit for definitions of the different `\and` commands. Could we work around this?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Nevermind, I solved it by combining the `\And` and `\AND`.

Comment: this is why questions should always have a complete test document, basically you posted a question that only you could answer, as no one else had any information about tje input.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, sorry about that. I probably even jumped the gun asking the question, just because I am new to LaTeX and didn't think I could ever solve it myself. No idea how it works, I am just googling commands as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the commands `\And` and `\AND`, like so:

```
\author{First Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\\And
  Second Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\\And
  Third Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\\AND
  Fourth Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\\And
  Fifth Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  {\tt email@domain} \\
}
```

Gave the desired result:
[image]